# Dokku: Expose two ports from an application

Tags: scala, ports, deploying, dokku

I am trying to deploy a Scala based application to dokku, the application runs a http server and a customised sshd server.

The problem I have is it seems that dokku only supports one port for the application.
I need dokku to expose both my applications ports to the web.

In docker this is possible and quite straight forward to do, but when I implement the same technique in the dokku file, I get an error.

Any suggestions on allowing two ports to be accessible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dokku: Listen to multiple ports from an app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184496/dokku-listen-to-multiple-ports-from-an-app)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is, after all, docker, you can use an ***ambassador***...

You will need a line like:

```
docker run -t -i -link mysql:mysql -name mysql_ambassador -p 3306:3306 ctlc/ambassador
```

Replacing with your port and mysql with your container name (from `docker images`)

See https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/deploying-multi-server-docker-apps-with-ambassadors

NOTE: Make sure you `docker pull svendowideit/ambassador:latest` before...